# Dropdown list in PHP MVC

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu, yii

I am looking for a way to create a drop down list depending on what the user chooses. If the user picks the package of one profile the the output will give the user a drop down list with 1 field if the user chooses two profiles the output will give the user a drop down with 2 fields. The code recently displays just one dropdown even if the user chooses the second option i am developing this website using PHP and javascript

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu <?= empty($business) ? 'hidden' : '' ?>" aria-labelledby="business_list">
<?php foreach ($business as $key => $item) : ?>
    <li><?= Html::a($item->name, ['social-manager/profiles', 'b' => $key]) ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have to do it with Javascript, you can't get it done just with PHP

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu <?php if(empty($business)) echo 'hidden'; ?> aria-labelledby="business_list">
<?php if(!empty($business)) {
   foreach($business as $key => $value){ ?>
      <li><?php echo $value->name;?></li>
   <?php }
} ?>
</ul>
```